# A Thunderbolt 3 adapter for M.2 SSD

Tags: ssd, ubuntu, thunderbolt

I use the live edition of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for work, and every day I pack up my 128Gb USB 3.0 thumb drive in the morning and drive to work, where I insert that drive back into my work computer.

The only problem has I've been having is the fact that my read and write speeds are incredible slow. I realized that both my home and work computers have Thunderbolt 3 ports. I was wondering if there was an adapter for a small M.2 SSD that would plug into those TB3 ports. I don't really care as to if it has an enclosure, I just need a way to easily transport an SSD that I can just plug into my computer and get Samsung 960 PRO-esque speeds. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you thought about getting an enclosure for a 2.5 SSD that has TB3? This is of course assuming you still need to purchase an SSD.

Comment: I have thought about it, but most of them have max speeds of ~500 Mb/s. I work in OS development, and it usually means I'm transferring tens of gigabytes of data to the main collaboration drive every day, and it can take a while. I kind of want something that can handle speeds of ~2500 Mb/s, like the Samsung 960.